# Drawing step functions

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs

How would I represent a one dimensional potential step such as the one shown in the attached figure? I've managed to get as far as defining my x and y axis but I'm not sure how to draw the function and insert the required labels. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE!

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[-stealth] (-pi,0) -- (pi,0) node[right]{$x$};
 \draw[-stealth] (0,0) -- (0,2) node[above]{$V(x)$};
 \draw[thick] (-pi,0) -- (0,0) node[below]{$0$} -- (0,1) node[left]{$V_0$} -- (pi,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's fantastic, thank you so much! Have a nice day